# Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have errors in my android manifest file:

```
Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\brandon\AndroidStudioProjects\MineDodge2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.x‌​ml
Error:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

I tried to look on this website but the answers aren't working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    < manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brandon.MineDodge" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/redjet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.Splash" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the error? Try removing the `intent-filter` from one of the `activity` entries.

Comment: Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\brandon\AndroidStudioProjects\MineDodge2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @ColinGillespie it still doesnt work

Comment: i also have another error that says

Comment: Error:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: do you have a closing `</manifest>` tag at the end?

Comment: yes . i just took out both intent filters and its still not working

Comment: The code you posted does not have a `</manifest>` tag. Please post your whole manifest file.

Comment: i have a ending manifest tag it's just not showing i dont know why

Comment: when i put it , it shows a read line under my application , manifest and the activity closing tag

Comment: if I read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) correctly, intent-flter tags should be inside activity tag scopes, and your second intent-filter is not? could this be causing issues?

Comment: second activity has no closing tag

Comment: i just put it in and its still not working

Comment: Are the paths correct for each package, i.e. you have com\example\brandon\MineDodge\Splash and com\example\brandon\MineDodge\MainActivity ?

Comment: yes everything it the same

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using an old version of **build.grade** file, you should remove this code:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}
```

Then, *Build > Clean Project*

**Note**: If you see this code, you are using the old version

Comment: how to know if I am using the old one?

Comment: If you see this code, you are using the old version.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error on Unity 2018 and i think it's a bug.

Fix for me:
Add packagename to Android Manifest in Unity project.

In my project path to manifest: `Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml`

For example i got error when my Manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
</manifest>
```

It generated by Oculus Gear VR plugin by Unity. But it missed package name and must looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest package="YOURPACKAGENAME" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
</manifest>
```

Replace YOURPACKAGENAME to Package Name of your project. It should be in Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings -> Identification -> Package Name and should looks like com.YOURORGANIZATION.APPNAME

Some peoples wrote, that manifest must looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest package="${applicationId}" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
</manifest>
```

And they wrote that Unity will replace `${applicationId}` on package name when build android application, but in my Unity 2018.1.6f1 it doesn't work and i think it's a bug too.

Comment: I'm using unity 2018 with Oculus Go (same plugin) and this answer worked for me. I'll also add that if your Unity project has multiple manifest files, then make sure to update the `<manifest package="YOURPACKAGENAME" ...` in those as well prior to performing a Gradle build.

Answer (score 3):

The error is really simple, and I'm rather dissapointed with the stack community to not have found it till now.

```
< manifest ...
```

should become

```
<manifest...
```

Basically, remove that extra space. That's what's causing the following error :

```
Error:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Also, the intent-filter used for the MainActivity, must similarly be used for the second activity.

Hope this issue is resolved.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.android.ex.chips"
          android:versionCode="1">
</manifest>
In above manifest I still have the error: Can not read package name from path\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
Remove the semicolon at the end of this line. xml doesn't use semicolons

Comment: This could also be a formatting issue - SE doesn't handle HTML/XML in code very well. But yeah, this could be a cause

Comment: this is not the problem,

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was trying to convert an old Eclipse project to Android Studio project where the manifest file is expected to be on a different location (along with other files). Specifically **project\app\src\main**

Answer (score 1):

In response to [Eldar Kurbanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8443671/eldar-kurbanov) who had this error in Unity & anyone else who finds this question after having the error when building with gradle in Unity.

This is not a Unity 2018 'bug' nor is it caused by something being missing from the Manifest pre-build. It's actually caused by the mainTemplate.gradle file missing the line:

```
applicationId '**APPLICATION**'
```

Inside the **defaultConfig {}** block of the **android {}** section. This will ensure the generated manifest has the package name inserted into it.

Yes manually inserting the package name into the main manifest *will work*, but it's much better to just use Unity's project settings to set the package name rather than hard-coding it.

If anyone else finds this question and they're using Unity then here's an example mainTemplate.gradle you can use for referencing: https://pastebin.com/hPs0uvkZ

Answer (score 0):

Your second `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` and 
            `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` are not allowed here.
I think 
`
    < manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brandon.MineDodge" >

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/redjet"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.Splash" />
</application>
```

`
That will be OK.

Comment: @BrandonT you have deleted <action><category>?And it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes for my splash activity

Comment: this is how the second activity looks now. <activity
            android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.Splash" >

    </activity>

Answer (score 0):

why you mentioned  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` twice? Remove any one from those two.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in a multi-subproject project, caused by the subproject not matching the `configure(` clause in the top-level `build.gradle`.

Specifically I had

```
configure(subprojects.findAll { it.name.startsWith("pachymeninx") }) {
```

which did not match my new subproject called `pachymen`.  But the Gradle build process issued no warning (that I saw) and instead gave "`Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml`" error for the `pachymen` subproject.

Comment: and again, just now

Answer (score 0):

Thats simply because you either copied an already existing project and its files into your newly created project. Thereby causing Manifest conflict. Because the manifest copied belongs to the other project and its paths.

you need to recreated a manifest file in your own project file path and possibly manually copy the other project's manifest code into your newly created manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your src file is named with some different name.....if thats the case then you might end up with this error....rename it to "src

Answer (score 0):

**check your manifest file should be at-> \android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml**

otherwise android can't find the package name in  Manifest file from a specific location

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the module level android manifest file was in the wrong location. It was inside `src/java/` whereas it is supposed to be in `src/`

Answer (score -1):

try this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brandon.MineDodge">

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/launchicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeTP">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeTP" >
    </activity>

    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.MainActivity"` should be under `<application>`, not under `<activity>`.

Answer (score -2):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.Splash" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</application>
```

change it to--

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.brandon.MineDodge.Splash" />
         <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</application>
```