# Error:Cannot read packageName from app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml

These are the errors that pop up when running my app for splash screen.

```
Error:The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
Error:Cannot read packageName from /Users/akellavamsimeher/AndroidStudioProjects/WILM/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I tried to resolve seeing posts from stackoverflow but I'm still stuck at that. Please help me fix these errors.

Here is the code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pratyuvamgmail.wilm">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        android:name="com.pratyuvamgmail.wilm.Splash" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action 
android:name="com.coderefer.androidsplashscreenexample.MAINACTIVITY"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

Below is my code...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pratyuvamgmail.wilm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            android:name="com.pratyuvamgmail.wilm.Splash" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.coderefer.androidsplashscreenexample.MAINACTIVITY"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Share you AndroidManifest file and make surre that your AndroidManifest.xml file start with: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.mypackagename" >

Comment: so were is the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447683/cannot-read-packagename-from-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 2):

First impression is that you manifest file  (`src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`) does not start like follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name" >
    ...
</manifest>
```

Or it has a invalid format...

Share your manifest file and then, we will be able to see exact error

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38824452/1200764) is checking that the `applicationId` is set in the  `defaultConfig` in `build.gradle` ,

[because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823794/android-studio-cannot-read-packagename-from-manifest#comment65015053_38824452) the `applicationId` in `build.gradle` overrides the `package` in `<manifest>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest is wrong, you have duplicate the tag close manifest and some tags have wrong open/close tags.

A simple example could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>
    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Check android documentation for more info:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Check if works this code for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pratyuvamgmail.wilm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: hi,i got the below errors after using the above code.