# Gradle sync failed: Cannot read packageName

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I have tried so many solutions but none worked. It would be great if someone could help here.I have imported this project which has API 21 however, I have API 26. If you want to know any further details from the code, please let me know.  I have completely no idea where I went wrong so it would be nice if anyone can tell me what are the possible fixes for this situation?

manifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapps.documentscanner"
    android:installLocation="auto">


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".DocumentScannerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <receiver android:name="WidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/simple_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />

        <!--
          Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
          dispatching on non-Google Play devices
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!--
             Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
             installation campaign reporting
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentScannerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_document_scanner"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GalleryGridActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SavedTextsList"
            android:label="@string/saved_texts_list"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:parentActivityName=".OcrCaptureActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".OcrCaptureActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- todo 5: Add provider to AndroidManifest.xml -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.myapps.documentscanner.data.TextProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapps.documentscanner" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TextDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/edit_text_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".SavedTextsList"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".SavedTextsList" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_full_image"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OcrCaptureActivity"
            android:label="Read Text"
            android:parentActivityName=".DocumentScannerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".DocumentScannerActivity" />
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
        App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapps.documentscanner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName '2.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    splits {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {

            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips" , 'armeabi'

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }

}

// Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, mips:3, x86:4]

// For per-density APKs, create a similar map like this:
// ext.densityCodes = ['mdpi': 1, 'hdpi': 2, 'xhdpi': 3]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ext.abiCodes * 1000 + variant.versionCode. In this example, variant.versionCode
// is equal to defaultConfig.versionCode. If you configure product flavors that
// define their own versionCode, variant.versionCode uses that value instead.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    // Assigns a different version code for each output APK
    // other than the universal APK.
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        // Stores the value of ext.abiCodes that is associated with the ABI for this variant.
        def baseAbiVersionCode =
                // Determines the ABI for this variant and returns the mapped value.
                project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        // Because abiCodes.get() returns null for ABIs that are not mapped by ext.abiCodes,
        // the following code does not override the version code for universal APKs.
        // However, because we want universal APKs to have the lowest version code,
        // this outcome is desirable.
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

            // Assigns the new version code to versionCodeOverride, which changes the version code
            // for only the output APK, not for the variant itself. Skipping this step simply
            // causes Gradle to use the value of variant.versionCode for the APK.
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.6'
    compile 'com.github.nostra13:Android-Universal-Image-Loader:v1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.fafaldo:fab-toolbar:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error is : Error:Cannot read packageName from E:\Document-Scanner-master\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823794/android-studio-cannot-read-packagename-from-manifest)  if it helps.

Comment: I did try this :/

Comment: You should add `applicationId` in build.gradle(Module:app) not build.gradle(Project:YourApp).

Comment: I have done that already!

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle and the full exception that you are seeing?

Comment: So nothing appears red in `AndroidManifest.xml` code?

Comment: No, there are a couple of things that appear red

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio : cannot read packageName from manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823794/android-studio-cannot-read-packagename-from-manifest)

Comment: OK you should try solving those red stuffs first.